# Export every item from array as separate variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm generating storybook documentation for react component. I already have a file with all versions of the prop for it.

Componet.stories.ts:

```
const stories: Story[] = data.map(
  (data, index) =>
    ({
      name: `Version ${index}`,
      args: {
        ...data
      }
    })
);


export const story0 = stories[0];
export const story1 = stories[1];
export const story2 = stories[2];
export const story3 = stories[3];
//...
```

I want to export each item from an array as a separate variable in a loop. Is it even possible?

Comment: Would it not make more sense, and be much, much easier, to just export the array?

Comment: Exporting data as array doesn't work for storybook

Comment: After exporting if you are planning to use in other component then better is to bind that component directly here.